# INNER JOIN Syntax Error

Tags: mysql

I get the follow error:

```
"Couldn't execute query. Duplicate column name 'id'"
```

When using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT count(*) as c FROM (
    SELECT *, CONCAT_WS(', ', subordinates.last_name, subordinates.first_name) AS subordinate_name 
    FROM orders 
    INNER JOIN subordinates ON orders.subordinate = subordinates.id WHERE orders.responsible = 8)
```

Both of the tables ("subordinates" and "orders") have an "id" column. Can I exclude the "id" column when joining the "subordinates" table?

I am using MySQL

Comment: What's the point of using `CONCAT_WS()` and `*` when you only want to count rows? You could just write `SELECT count(*) as c FROM orders o JOIN subordinates s ON o.subordinate = s.id WHERE o.responsible = 8;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the query to something like

```
SELECT count(*) as c 
FROM    (
        SELECT orders .*, CONCAT_WS(', ', subordinates.last_name, subordinates.first_name) AS subordinate_name 
        FROM orders INNER JOIN subordinates ON orders.subordinate = subordinates.id 
        WHERE orders.responsible = 8
    )
```

To ensure that you only have one `Id` in the subselect.

You just neem to make sure that you do not have duplicate names in the sub select.

Also, a general rule of thumb is to not use `SELECT *` as it can greatly impact perfomance

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT count(*) as c 
FROM (
    SELECT orders.*, 
        CONCAT_WS(', ', subordinates.last_name, subordinates.first_name) AS subordinate_name 
    FROM orders 
    INNER JOIN subordinates 
    ON orders.subordinate = subordinates.id 
    WHERE orders.responsible = 8)
```